# WSO2 ESB Cache mediation to cache a config file

Tags: caching, wso2, smooks, wso2-esb

I need to get some configs from a my xml config file. Due to the high load it is a bad idea to read data from file for each proxy service invocation. I found smooks and cache mediators and I think these two mediators can help me but I don't know how. Also I've heard of VFS transports but since I have the large scale and high load of requests I have to reduce the service invokation or reading from files and handle this problem with some cached data in server RAM.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a database to build a persistent cache, so that you can do a dblookup before reading the file. This mediation logic can be defined within the ESB where the ESB will do a DBlookup before accessing the file. Similarly for a new entry you can create a cache entry in the DB.

If you are still interested in cache mediator the following link will help
[1] http://soa.dzone.com/articles/wso2-esb-cache-mediator

Comment: I don't understand how it can be better, I want to cache my requests because they are all the same since they are config data. I think I couldn't understand your answer I don't know how can it better and what is the strategy of your idea of implementation. tnx for your help.